# Can one javascript file be included in two HTML documents?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Can I use one script file in two different HTML files (HTML1 and HTML2). How can I specify which document to get the element form when I use DOM? Or will it automatically identify which document is by the element id??

Comment: You can use your JS in as many HTML files as you want. It will have access only to the DOM of the page it was included into.

Comment: As a programmer, the first thing you should have done is try it out and see what happens. If you still didn't understand the behavior, then you could post here with your findings and ask for help.

Comment: Javascript just uses the elements in the page that loads it. Other pages that also use it are irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Take javascript [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)s for an example, you potentially have one javascript file used by millions of websites, let alone web pages.

The script itself doesn't care or know what page has loaded it. It is loaded by the browser and if you are doing DOM manipulation it works with whatever DOM has been loaded into the browser via the HTML in the loaded page.

It is up to you, the developer, to make sure that you have the appropriate hooks in your HTML for your javascript to use.